# Spring Boot Microservices hitting same microservice multiple time

Tags: java, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am using eureka server
My problem is that 
Microservice X tries to Call Microservice Y but Microservice X call Microservice Y multiple times instead of 1 time , It happens only when implementation service taken more time to respond.

X is hitting using

```
    @RequestMapping(path="/catalogs/getCatalogList",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> getCatalogList() throws RestException;
```

and using @FeignClient("XYZ")

And Y is using

```
@RequestMapping(path="/getCatalogList",method = RequestMethod.GET)
getCatalogList()
```

And getCatalogList is been hit many times if it takes too much to response

Comment: Which http client is X using?

Comment: restControlller is not an HTTP client.  Are you using HttpClient or maybe RestTemplate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Problem occurs because Ribbon does the retry when there is connection time-out. For details on that check [spring retry](http://ryanjbaxter.com/cloud/spring%20cloud/spring/2017/03/15/retrying-http-requests-in-spring-cloud-netflix.html) . To fix this issue you can follow below step :-

- In **application.properties** of your Microservice X `feignClientName.ribbon.OkToRetryOnAllOperations=false` and you also check more properties here [application.yml](https://github.com/spencergibb/spring-cloud-sandbox/blob/master/spring-cloud-sandbox-sample-frontend/src/main/resources/application.yml)